# Can't find TC117HS and RX28 data sheets

Tags: schematics, datasheet

I am trying to adapt an RC car to control it with an arduino. In order to do that I am trying to understand the PCB.

In the car PCB, there are:

- one "**RX28 TXM ZYX13AA**" with 16 pins
- two "**TC117HS CE1P1D**" with 8 pins

Where can i find the data sheets?

I only find the "**TC117HS CE1P1D**" in chinese.

Comment: Not all chips have an English datasheet, particularly for cut-rate products like an RC car. However, a Google search will at least turn up pinouts and block diagram for a TC117HS. If you have access to an oscilloscope, poke around the board while twiddling the remote, and I think you will very quickly be able to find the PWM signals.

Comment: Post photos of the chips (often the fonts, logos and chip shape can provide more clues). I suspect 'RX28' is actually RX2B, the receiver part of the Realtek TX2/RX2 chipset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed, nothing turns up in English as specified - you might ask the manufacturers if English documents of those exact models exist. However, here is the next best thing:

[TX-2B/RX-2B](http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/27MHz%20Transmitters/imagesP2/RX2Bdatasheet-5function.pdf): 5-function remote controller (thanks to Bruce Abbott)

[Comprehensible translation](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://superchip.cn/Private/ProductFiles/TC117HS%25EF%25BC%2588%25E5%258D%2595%25E9%2580%259A%25E9%2581%2593%25E7%259B%25B4%25E6%25B5%2581%25E9%25A9%25AC%25E8%25BE%25BE%25E9%25A9%25B1%25E5%258A%25A8%25E5%2599%25A8%25EF%25BC%2589.pdf&prev=search) of the [Chinese datasheet for TC117HS](http://superchip.cn/Private/ProductFiles/TC117HS%EF%BC%88%E5%8D%95%E9%80%9A%E9%81%93%E7%9B%B4%E6%B5%81%E9%A9%AC%E8%BE%BE%E9%A9%B1%E5%8A%A8%E5%99%A8%EF%BC%89.pdf)